# AMD modules in coffeescript without indenting the entire file?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, amd

When writing AMD modules in coffeescript, because everything is wrapped in a function, every file ends up looking like this:

```
define 'myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2'], (dep1, dep2) ->
    funcA: ->
    funcB: ->
    # etc...
    funcZ: ->
```

I like to minimize indentation in my code to make it easier to understand, and I dislike how AMD adds a level of indentation to almost everything. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for now, unfortunately. But a feature proposal that would address exactly this kind of use-case (and others, especially regarding asynchronous callback code and Callback Hell in general) [is being actively discussed in the CoffeeScript Issues](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2662). The proposed feature is called "backcalls" and it's basically a syntactic transformation to get this kind of callback nested code to look more sequential. Your module definition would look like:

```
(dep1, dep2) <- define 'myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2']

funcA: ->
funcB: ->
# etc...
funcZ: ->
```

---

If you want something working *right now*, one thing you can do is to add a preprocessor step to your build configuration so that the `define ...` line and the indentation gets added before getting into the CoffeeScript compiler.

You could declare your modules with some special comments on the .coffee source:

```
#!module=myModule
#!dependencies=dep1,dep2

funcA: ->
funcB: ->
# etc...
funcZ: ->
```

And then have a script that would read those comments and generate the `define 'myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2'], (dep1, dep2) ->` line and add one level of indentation to every line in the input file.

So your build steps would look something like:

```
cat myModule.coffee | add-amd | coffee -sc > myModule.js
```

Comment: The backcall syntax looks interesting. I think that if I were to add a preprocessing step it would be a commonJS to AMD converter.

Comment: @gregsabo That's a good alternative. Better yet: it seems [RequireJS provides a tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) that does exactly that. It seems the `r.js` tool is a JS code transformer though, so it would have to be a post-processor after the CoffeeScript compiler. Good luck with that :)